# How to use an underscore in a filename

Tags: symbols, write

With the commands `\openout` and `\write` I output text into a file. I want this file to have a name of containing an underscore (eg. `name_01.txt`), but I'm unable to get the underscore in the filename. My attempt (with `\_`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile="name\_01.txt"
\immediate\write\tempfile{this is interesting}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\immediate\openout\tempfile="name\string_01.txt"
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation and say what and why it works? StackExchange answers should not consist of a single line but a full answer

Answer (score 4):

well, i ve just tried the simple

```
\immediate\openout\tempfile="name_01.txt"
```

... and it works ... Sorry. :)

Comment: When I opened the question I was thinking exactly the same. :) Underscores (and other special characters I won't mention) are legal without any special precautions in a file name. Beware that at least one package makes the underscore active and, in this case, Herbert's solution is the best approach.

Comment: By the way, how can i output a "tabulation" character ? can i also use \string in some way ?

Comment: Tabs are quite strange beasts; there is something about this problem on the site.