# How to escape a list of underscored filenames efficiently?

Tags: symbols, write, environment-variables

I am thinking how to read a CSV file which has filenames which have underscores efficiently into a LaTeX variable. 
I think reading the raw variables into a variable by `input` and then manipulating items etc in a `pgffor` loop may not be optimum. 
I am thinking if you can escape the underscores at the same time when you read them into the variable.
Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\mylist}{\input{/home/masi/filelist.csv}}
\begin{document}
\mylist
\end{document}
```

filelist.csv

```
IMG_20161215_081851.jpg,
IMG_20161215_090559.jpg,
IMG_20161215_091308.jpg
```

Output with XeLaTeX

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.1 IMG_
        20161215_081851.jpg,
? 
)
```

### Pseudocode based on the thread

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% TODO here apply escape on a list; what is the good way here?     
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58689/13173

\immediate\openout\tempfile="name\string_01.txt"

\newcommand{\mylist}{\input{/home/masi/filelist.csv}}

\begin{document}
\mylist
\end{document}
```

### Minimum example for looping filenames in `includegraphics`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for importing .pdf images     
\newsavebox{\imgbox}

\newcommand{\mylist}{\input{/home/masi/filelist.csv}}

\begin{document}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341553/13173
\centering
\foreach \ii in {\mylist} {
  \IfFileExists{/home/masi/\ii}{
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \savebox{\imgbox}{% Store image in a box
      \includegraphics[height=.9\paperheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{/home/masi/\ii}
    }%
    \ifdim\ht\imgbox = \paperheight
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{/home/masi/\ii}}
    }%
    \else
      \usebox{\imgbox}%
    \fi
    \caption{Case}
    \end{figure}
  }{}
} % closing brace for loop

\end{document}
```

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Why don't you use a package for CSV-reading? `datatool` for example? [Or another related package](http://ctan.org/topic/data-import)

Comment: @Johannes_B Can you give please an example?

Comment: Do you want to print the contents of the csv file? I guess you don't. This seems an XY question

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Then you don't need to escape the underscores, because `\includegraphics` accepts them.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 *That's* the code you should show.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Your habit of randomly deleting you comments is quite confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape underscores, as `\includegraphics` accepts them.

Your main error is in thinking that `\mylist` expands to a list of filenames separated by commas. It doesn't.

You can use `\CatchFileDef`, for that. But also remember not to brace `\mylist` after `\foreach`.

In the code below I removed all `/home/masi/` strings for obvious reasons. I copied the usual example graphic files under the names in `filelist.csv`, so to get the required output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for importing .pdf images
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newsavebox{\imgbox}
\CatchFileDef{\mylist}{filelist.csv}{\endlinechar=-1 }

\begin{document}

\foreach \ii in \mylist {
  \IfFileExists{\ii}{
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \savebox{\imgbox}{% Store image in a box
      \includegraphics[height=.9\paperheight,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{\ii}
    }%
    \ifdim\ht\imgbox = \paperheight
      \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{\ii}}
    }%
    \else
      \usebox{\imgbox}%
    \fi
    \caption{Case}
    \end{figure}
  }{}
} % closing brace for loop

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I can't see what the conditional is supposed to do, because the figure height will always be at most `.9\paperheight` and so never equal to `\paperheight`.

The `filelist.csv` file I used is the same as yours:

```
IMG_20161215_081851.jpg,
IMG_20161215_090559.jpg,
IMG_20161215_091308.jpg
```

Here's the output of `ls` in the directory I made for the example:

```bsh
> ls
IMG_20161215_081851.jpg     filelist.csv        masid.pdf
IMG_20161215_090559.jpg     masid.aux           masid.tex
IMG_20161215_091308.jpg     masid.log
```

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Of course I did.

Comment: Confirmed, this works! I had to set `\extrafloats{1000}; \maxdeadcycles=1000`, and also fix missing `/` in `graphicspath`.

Answer (score 4):

The category code of the underscore can be locally changed from 8 (math subscript) to 12 (category "other") to get rid of the special meaning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\mylist}{\input{/home/masi/filelist.csv}}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@makeother\_%
  \mylist
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Or

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\_=12 %
  \mylist
\endgroup
```

Category codes are assigned, when the input is read. If a file name is already tokenized, the category codes cannot be changed via `\catcode`.
If a macro `\myfilename` contains the file name, then it can be sanitized by:

```
\@onelevel@sanitize\myfilename
```

Or e-TeX's `\detokenize` can be used:

```
\detokenize\expandafter{\myfilename}
```

Comment: Can you change the meaning of the underscore in the variable such that it can be looped?